# I am using custom validator constraint ContainsFullname to validate a route parameter but found no route error

Tags: symfony

I have created a constraint class **ContainsFullname** and a validator class **ContainsFullnameValidator** to check provided constraint param following the fullname pattern or not. Then I have registered **ContainsFullname** class service and used it in the **requirements** option for **guestName** constraint, but when I hit **/get/entrance/permission/Nusaiba%20Noor**, I am getting **No route found for "GET /get/entrance/permission/Nusaiba%20Noor"**.

**ContainsFullname.php**

```
<?php 

namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class ContainsFullname extends Constraint {

    public $message = "Provided {{invalidFullname}} is invalid.(Example: Md Nazmul Huda)";

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return \get_class($this) . 'Validator';
    }

}
```

**ContainsFullnameValidator.php**

```
<?php 

namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;
use AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\ContainsFullname;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Exception\UnexpectedTypeException;

class ContainsFullnameValidator extends ConstraintValidator {

    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {   
        if(!$constraint instanceof ContainsFullname) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, ContainsFullname::class);
        } 
        
        if(!$value) return;

        if(!is_string($value)) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($value, 'string');
        }

        if(!preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z]+\s+)*[a-zA-Z]+$/i", $value, $matches)) {
            $this->context
                ->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->setParameter('{{invalidFullname}}', $value)
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }

}
```

**services.yml**

```
app.validator.contains_fullname:
        class: AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\ContainsFullname
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: app.validator.contains_fullname }
```

**routing.yml**

```
get.entrance.permission:
  path: /get/entrance/permission/{guestName}
  defaults:
    _controller: AppBundle:LearnRouting:getEntrancePermission
    guestName: null
  requirements:
    guestName: '@app.validator.contains_fullname'
```

I have checked my code to the provided symfony 3.4 documentation but found no differences, when removing constraint from requirement, the error goes but I need that implementation